# How do sites like Facebook ensure vanity URLs don't conflict with internal pages/folders?

Tags: facebook, url-rewriting, url-shortener, vanity-url

Sites like FB offer you a shallow "vanity" URL of your choice to give out to people like facebook.com/examplestore

But because its so shallow in depth, it could easily conflict with internal pages. For example if I register the vanity URL of facebook.com/jobs then that means Facebook can never add a "Jobs" section to their site in the future without changing their URL. If they try to get rid of the existing page (maybe its a fan page for Steve Jobs) then it would mess up SEO for that page anyway.

I have thought that there should be a list of reserved words stored in a database table and the choice of vanity URL could be checked against that. But is this the only way to do it?

It would mean having to brainstorm every single possible section/page you may EVER have on your site (e.g. settings, index,... potentially any other section in the site) and even then you could miss a few. Is there any alternative/better way to do it?